# How the Foundry Model Adapter Wrapped Model Works with Transform Where Stage and Model is Used?

Tags: model, adapter, palantir-foundry

I have in my main Foundry repo a Scikit based ML model where I use it along with my data pipeline using Stage and Model syntax. Now I want to use custom model adapter from another repo where Foundry has a simple example for scikit based model adapter. (`Palantir Foundry model adapter - only returning 22 results no matter what the input is`)

So If I use model adapter in lieu of Stage(), how do I assemble pipeline using Stage() based data pipeline (scikit Pipeline) with model adapter wrapped ML model? I have seen an example on this site where it used adapter to replace Stage() and Model() all together. Not sure if this is OK and reconcile with Foundry pipeline?

Comment: Are you attempting to combine a Model Adapter with a `foundry_ml` backed model? Model Adapters act as an alternative for `foundry_ml` but it's not possible to easily chain those together.

Instead, it's recommended to use pipelines from open source frameworks like scikit-learn, or to write your own chaining logic in the `run_inference` function in the model adapter.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely makes sense. But putting scikit pipeline inside run_inference function() is doubtful.